# Submit Button - any way to pass hidden element data?

Tags: html, submit, html-input

Alright, stupid simple question.  I'm not very savvy with HTML.  I have the following HTML:

```
<input type='submit' name='submitActivate' value='Activate'></input>
```

"Activate" is the text on the submit button.  When I post the form, I can grab the input's value data on the destination page (which would be the string "Activate").  Is there a way to do something like the following:

```
<input type='submit' name='submitActivate' value='Activate' hiddenData='ABC123'></input>
```

And on the posted page, be able to grab this element's "hiddenData" attribute data?

Answer (score 1):

Using a hidden input tag can achieve what you are wanting. You can wrap the button and a hidden input tag in a form like so:

```
<form onSubmit="doThis(hiddenData)">
  <input type='hidden' name='hiddenData' value='ABC123'>
  <input type='submit' name='submitActivate' value='Activate'></input>
</form>
```

Then in JS you can access the hidden input with:

```
doThis = function(hiddenData) {
  console.log(hiddenData.value) //logs ABC123
}
```

Hope this helps